# Hard Wrap for TextField in Django

Tags: django-models, model, textfield

I am using `TextField` in django and I have a form for the user to enter a passage. I want this passage to be saved with hard wrap in such a way that it appears the exact same way in terms of spacing and indentation when displayed later.

When I use the admin tool to enter the passage, it appears as I want it. But, when I reference it in a template, all the sentences flow together without the correct spacing and newlines. How do I make the TextField hard wrap when used in a template?

Here is my TextField declaration:

```
class Description(models.Model):
summary=models.TextField(verbose_name="My Summary")
```

I input through the admin the following sample:

```
Hi I am using TextField in django and I have a form for the user to enter a passage. 

I want this passage to be saved with hard wrap in such a way that it appears the exact
same in terms of spacing and indentation and what not. When I use the admin to enter
the passage,

It appears as I want it but when I reference it on a template. All the sentences follow
up without the correcect spacing and newlines. how do I achieve this please
```

It doesn't appear exactly like above when I use `info=Description.objects.get(pk=1)` in views or `{{ info }}` in templates.